# Error pages not working as expected on jboss as 7.1.1

Tags: java, servlets, exception, jboss, web.xml

I have configured my web app to show some error pages based on the exception type, but the problem is that if I configure a generic error page for java.lang.Exception, every exception is redirected to this generic error page.

My web.xml file:

```
<!-- error pages -->
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthorizedException</exception-type>
    <location>/acesso-nao-autorizado</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/login/</location>
</error-page>
    <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/erro</location>
</error-page>
```

As you can see, I have two specific exception types, than I have java.lang.Exception as a last resource. If I remove this last entry, then every exception redirects the user to the correct view. But with this last entry, it does not matter what type is the exception thrown, the user will always get redirected to /error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Servlet Spec 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf) (Section 10.9.2):

> "The Web application may have declared error pages using the `exception-type` element. In this case the container matches the exception type by comparing the exception thrown with the list of `error-page` definitions that use the `exception-type` element. A match results in the container returning the resource indicated in the `location` entry. The closest match in the class hierarchy wins."

So what you are doing should work ... and the order of your `error-page` elements should not matter.  (JBoss 6.0.0 and later support the Servlet Spec 3.0 ...)

My advice:

- Check that the exception *really* is the one you are expecting.
- Check that the redirection to the wrong page isn't happening for other reasons; e.g. the specific error pages throwing exceptions themselves.
- Check the JBoss issue tracker for related bugs.